# Application crashes if a property name starts with new

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobject, llvm-clang

In my project I'm using coredata. One of the entity has an attribute named **newTotal**, in its corresponding NSManagedObject class the property declaration is like

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *newTotal;
```

If I add a property like this in an NSObject subclass the XCode will show an error like

```
error: property's synthesized getter follows Cocoa naming convention for returning 'owned' objects
```

But in NSManaged object subclasses it's not showing the error but the application crashes when the property is accessed, something saying like **EXC_BAD_ACCESS**.

Why XCode not showing error but application crashes?. Is this a bug with XCode/clang/LLVM ?

I know its something related to the synthesize. NSManagedObject sub classes not synthesizing the property in it, but the @dynamic directive just tells the compiler that the getter and setter methods are implemented not by the class itself but somewhere else (like the superclass or will be provided at runtime). But I have no clear Idea about this. Can anybody can give a clear idea about the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can see you are using ARC.

In ARC memory is managed for you, but there are few things you can/have to do yourself. You cannot name property "newXxxx" because:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html

You cannot give an accessor a name that begins with new. This in turn means that you can’t, for example, declare a property whose name begins with new unless you specify a different getter:

// Won't work:

```
@property NSString *newTitle;
```

// Works:

```
@property (getter=theNewTitle) NSString *newTitle;
```

Comment: I know that,but why in NSMAnageObject subclasses not showing error but application crashes

Comment: NSManagedObject is used for Non-Standard Persistent Attributes mostly. It allows you to use objects or data structures not directly supported in iOS. I could speculate that by sub-classing this object, you bypass any regular memory checks since this could stop you from using your desired data structure.

Comment: But why you need that error to be shown. You know that you are not allowed to do this, and just avoid it, and everything will be fine.

Comment: For more info, please refer to NSManagedObject docs: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObject_Class/Reference/NSManagedObject.html

Comment: Because not everyone knows that error, and since ARC was presented far later than xCode itself with manual memory management, many old developers had to see that warning to know, that some new naming rules are implemented.

Comment: @Johnykutty: The Core Data attribute `newTotal` does not cause a compiler error because it is `@dynamic`. The compiler does not "know" the ownership semantics of the dynamically created getter method, therefore it assumes that everything is OK. - Of course, the Core Data Model compiler could warn about that, but it doesn't.